# How to pass extra data in AJAX success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a function:

```
function Activity() {
    this.LoadFile = function (path, onSuccess) {
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: onSuccess
        });
    };
}
```

At the moment I call it like this:

```
var activity = new Activity();

activity.LoadFile('../file.htm', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

What I would like to do, is to add some default values in the AJAX success callback. Lets say that for example, I always want to log the data by default, without writing it every time I do a `LoadFile`. Hope you get the point, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a wrapper function that logs/etc then calls the `onSuccess` function:

```
this.LoadFile = function (path, onSuccess) {
    var onSuccessWrapper = function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      onSuccess(data)
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: onSuccessWrapper
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do the folowing

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried this?

```
 $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            onSuccess(data);
            alert(data);//default here
        }
    });
```